# What kind of component does Apple Watch Photos App use

Tags: ios, watchkit

I want to create an Photo Viewing App for Apple watch with view similar to that of apple watch's photo app.

Here a [demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RzCLNBWrZjs) of what I need. I want to zoom into the photos using the digital crown. Also having a selection ability.

However with the current samples and app demo's out there, I an not sure what components this view is made of.

If anyone knows a solution to this kind of implementation please help me with it.

A sample code / code snippet / tutorial will be much appreciated